# How does one raise the position of the navigation bar's main title?

Tags: ios, swift

I have searched the internet thoroughly and cannot find how to adjust how high up the navigationItem.title appears. I am referring to the title that shows up in the middle of the navigation bar.

Comment: Is using the `titleView` property an option?

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment` function of `UINavigationBar` which will let you set an required vertical offset (can be positive or negative) for navigation bar title. Read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624959-settitleverticalpositionadjustme).

---

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

**Tomas**' answer is the simplest one. Except of that you could use a custom `titleView`. That way you can inset the text horizontally as well as vertically:

```
class TitleView: UIView {

    private let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
        return label
    }()

    var title: String? {
        get { return label.text }
        set { label.text = newValue }
    }

    convenience init(title: String, inset: UIEdgeInsets) {
        self.init()

        label.text = title

        addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: inset.top).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: inset.left).isActive = true
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: inset.bottom).isActive = true
        trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.trailingAnchor, constant: inset.right).isActive = true
    }

}
```

Then you can simply use it like this:

```
let titleView = TitleView(title: "TitleView", inset: .init(top: -10, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
vc.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```